# Jqtouch performs poorly when wrapped on jqt DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I have a iphone site based on JQTouch. When the pages are not wrapped in the  it performs flawlessly. When it is wrapped in the DIV animations are inconsistent, pages overlap and are totally broken on Android.

I would just abandon the jqt div but that breaks the 'Spinning wheel' by cubiq.

$Revision: 166 $
$Date: Tue Mar 29 01:24:46 EDT 2011 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jqtouch.css file seems to have not been updated at the same time as jqtouch. Updated and problem solved.